# Is There a Way to Capture How Long a Key is Pressed Down?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keyboard-events

I'm building a small app with React and want to be able to program functionality in which the user holds down a key, and the amount of time the key is pressed down for is captured. I do not want to capture when a button is clicked.

So far I have this:

```
import { KeyboardEvent } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const handleKeyChange = (e: KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (e.key === "y") alert("yes");

    if (e.key === "n") alert("no");
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Press the 'y' or 'n' key"
        onKeyPress={handleKeyChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: @vera. in this case the original question was wrongly closed. See [my comment there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75125342/is-there-a-way-to-capture-how-long-a-key-is-pressed-down-for-typescript-react#comment132576467_75125342). Now while helpmepie should have appealled that closure, they are a new user, and the mod who closed it did that to fast and presumtuously. So the real error is on the mod side, not the new user.

Comment: They are not a new user. They have been a contributor for 5 years. Secondly, as I replied to your comment on the previous question, the duplicate answered the time delta calculation. The last piece of the puzzle is to research how to bind an event handler, which is also easily researchable, and has been answered countless times already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp` events:

```
    import { KeyboardEvent } from "react";

    const App = () => {
      let date;
      const handleKeyDown = (e: React.KeyboardEvent) => {
        date = + new Date()
      };
      const handleKeyUp = (e: React.KeyboardEvent) => {
        const diff = +new Date() - this.date();
        // do whatever you want with the diff
      };
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <input
            type="text"
            onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
            onKeyUp={handleKeyUp}
          />
        </div>
      );
    };

    export default App;
```

Comment: it is also possible to restrict allowed keys by only setting date when a permitted key is down in  `handleKeyDown`